# Mysql - Why does count on an indexed column takes so long?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I a simple query, counting number of items. 
The table items has 1.5M records. From some reason, running the query takes 65 seconds!
The query returns 30,000

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `items`
WHERE `items`.`owner_id`
  IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
AND items.is_hidden = false
```

EDIT: added the 'and' clause to fully describe problem

Explain shows that the query is using this index:

```
1   SIMPLE  items   range   idx_owner   idx_owner   4   NULL    258 Using index condition; Using where
```

And these are the table's indexes:

```
items   0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   1444298 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
items   1   items_a951d5d6  1   slug    A   288859  767 NULL        BTREE       
items   1   category_id_refs_id_3b77a81e    1   category_id A   34  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
items   1   origin_id_refs_id_99b3fd12  1   origin_id   A   2   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
items   1   parent_id_refs_id_99b3fd12  1   parent_id   A   6   NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
items   1   name    1   name    A   1444298 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
items   1   idx_owner   1   owner_id    A   722149  NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

Why is it taking so long? Any way to improve it?

Comment: Why the `LIMIT 50`? It will never return more than one row anyway

Comment: You are completely right. I'm very sorry, copy pasted that by mistake.

Comment: Try `COUNT(id)` instead of `COUNT(*)`

Comment: I tried that as well, doesn't change much

Comment: There no need for `ORDER BY items.id`. Try this query: `SELECT count(*)
FROM items
WHERE owner_id >=1 AND owner_id <= 8`

Comment: thanks rims, Your query runs very fast. But what if the owner ids aren't adjacent? I Tried removing the order_by. it still takes a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use temporary table and JOIN:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE owner_ids (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO owner_ids VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8);

SELECT count(*)
FROM items
JOIN owner_ids ON owner_ids.id = items.owner_id
```

Comment: This does make the work almost immediate! However, sorry for keeping making changes... If I append an and - such as and items.is_hidden = false it still takes almost 2 minutes

Comment: To speed up try to create index: `CREATE INDEX items_i2 ON items(owner_id, is_hidden);`

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an index of both columns:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_both_columns ON `items` (`owner_id`, `is_hidden`);
```